# Optimal design for separating traffic from 1 program through 2nd router while leaving all the other programs going through 1st router?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, proxy, routing, lan

I have the following network setup Speedport Router(integrated modem) - this one gets DSL internet connection (250 / 40 Mbps) Linksys EA6900 Router (without modem) - this one is connected to the speedport for the internet connection. I have a computer on which I have a network interface (intel integrated) and a wifi usb card (some belkin 802.11g).

Since I want to download some stuff (torrents via uTorrent) which I may want to do it in secret via VPN, I was thinking of doing this by connecting a Linksys router to PureVPN (I have an account there) and any traffic through the Linksys router would be encrypted and secure, albeit slower and with bigger latency which I don't really mind. Even then if I feel that this is too slow I can change the VPN server to another one. I usually use NL, SWE or LUX servers for P2P.

Anything else would go directly through Speedport router which has the lowest latency because it is a direct internet connection.

I was thinking of doing it in the following way: Connect NIC with Speedport router via cat 6 cable, and I have already done this. Connect belkin wifi with Linksys EA6900 wirelessly, and I have already done this. Now I plan to mod the Linksys EA6900 into a Asuswrt Merlin firmware via this guide: https://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/asuswrt-merlin-build-384-5-or-later-on-linksys-ea6900-or-ea6700.74209/ (this will be a challange in its own right).

Now comes the part where I force the uTorrent to use the secure VPN connection for its traffic. I was thinking of 2 options: 1. use Net Limiter to achieve this, force the uTorrent to use wifi connection to EA6900 router. 2. set up a proxy server on the Linksys EA6900 with Asuswrt Merlin firmware and then setup the uTorrent to use the proxy from the IP address which is given to Linksys EA6900 on the Speedport router. That way it will utilize the secret VPN connection on the EA6900 but going through Speedport to which it is connected via cable thereby reducing the latency even more than with wifi connection.

What do you guys think? Do you have some suggestions, some comments, some improvements, some alternatives which might be easier or less of a hassle? Any feedback would be good.

Since as you can see, I have this pretty much worked out (at least in theory) I was just wondering and wanted to see if somebody has already had a similar scenario and has done all this, if this is feasible (especially the proxy server on the EA6900 part), even more so if somebody has an even better idea on how to solve this.

EDIT: I have just checked and have found out that I also have an integrated NIC on the motherboards, so it makes 2 NICs, 1 external and 1 integrated and a wifi dongle stick. OS is Windows 10.
If I were to connect NIC1 to Router 1 and NIC2 to Router 2, how to specify which one takes precedence in the windows settings? One would be secure via VPN and the other would be direct internet connection as already stated.

Comment: What OS are you using on your PC?

Comment: It is a Windows 10.

Comment: I was going to suggest using network namespace (`ip netns`) until I read the windows part. Two suggestions, establish the VPN on your device and tell torrent client to only bind to tunnel interface, use a VPN provider that also gives you a SOCKS proxy and use SOCKS proxy in torrent client (or proxifier).

Comment: Do your routers support "quality of service"?

Comment: If You want to have this specifically for uTorrent You may be able to utilize outgoing_ip (and bind_ip) settings for that.